# Are there any ways to use a string from string.xml for item name of arrays.xml in Android?

Tags: android, xml

My question is very simple. I made arrays.xml in my project and I wannt to manage all of the string of my project in strings.xml. But, when I search on Google, all of people defined string directly in the item like below.

```
<string-array name="media_names">
        <item>Big Buck Bunny</item>
        <item>Elephants Dream</item>
        <item>Sintel</item>
        <item>Tears of Steel</item>
</string-array>
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use normal @string like in xml

array.xml

```
<string-array name="media_names">
   <item>@string/item1</item>
   <item>@string/item2</item>
   <item>@string/item3</item>
   <item>@string/item4</item>
</string-array>
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="item1">Big Buck Bunny 1</string> 
<string name="item2">Big Buck Bunny 2</string> 
<string name="item3">Big Buck Bunny 3</string> 
<string name="item4">Big Buck Bunny 4</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the string value like you would in other XML files.

```
<string name="big_buck_bunny">Big Buck Bunny</string> 
<string-array name="media_names">
        <item>@string/big_buck_bunny</item>
        <item>etc</item>
</string-array>
```